# LLDB evaluations run out of memory on iOS. How can I free some memory?

Tags: ios, debugging, memory, memory-management, lldb

In LLDB console on iOS, I repeated

```
(lldb) p/x $r1
(unsigned int) $1 = 0x07000006

(lldb) p/x $r1
(unsigned int) $2 = 0x07000006

(lldb) p/x $r1
(unsigned int) $3 = 0x07000006
 ...etc
```

about 1500 times, and finally got the following error message

```
error: Couldn't allocate space for the stack frame: Couldn't malloc: address space is full
Errored out in Execute, couldn't PrepareToExecuteJITExpression
```

As far as I understand it, each time I run `p/x $r1`, the debugger evaluates `$r1` as an expression and allocates a buffer in a memory for a temporary variable `$N` (where `N = 1, 2, 3, ...`). After about 1500 evaluations, the debugger run out of memory and can't allocate buffers anymore.

My question is how can I free some memory? E.g. if I do not need the temporary variable `$1` anymore, can I do something like `free($1)`? Are there any "secret" lldb commands for that?

Thanks in advance for your answers.

Comment: Check available free memory, maybe you don't have any. If it's the case, sudo purge in Terminal may help, it'll free some memory.

Comment: I'll try, thanks! Probably it will help to free some unused memory. However, I'd like to know how to free a buffer allocated, for example, for `$1`. Something like `free($1)`. Any ideas?

Comment: Unfortunately no, I have no idea. I've tried to find something here ( http://lldb.llvm.org/lldb-gdb.html ), but didn't see anything related.

Comment: @Timur Kuchkarov, yes, I read the official documentation and didn't find any LLDB commands like the one I need. Anyway, thanks for your answer :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you doing `p/x $r1` because you need to preserve value of $r1 in a temporary, or do you just want to see its value?  If the latter, you can use:

```
(lldb) register read/x r1
```

which can be shortened to:

```
(lldb) re r/x r1
```

That directly prints the register without constructing a temporary.  Similarly, if you just want to see the value of a local variable:

```
(lldb) frame variable foo
```

will print the value of foo without going through the full expression parser.

Note, there is also a bug in the current lldb that causes expressions to allocate way more memory than they need to - 1500 expressions is too few for you to really be running out of memory, even on a 32 bit system...  That's been fixed in the lldb.llvm.org sources, but I don't know when the fix will make its way into a release.

There isn't currently a way to tell lldb either not to make, or to discard, these convenience variables.  There's no reason this couldn't be done, there just hasn't been a need for it.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! Actually, I need to evaluate numerous complex expressions like `$sp+$r0+0x602-0x1000+*(int*)($sp+0x10)` during a debugging session, sometimes I run out the limit of ~1500 evaluations. Also, in my Python scripts I also use `EvaluateExpression()` lldb API, and have the same problem: a script can't call `EvaluateExpression()` more that about 1500 times because of memory limit. Tricks like calling `SBValue::Clean()` do not work for me :( I will hope the fixes will come from the lldb.llvm.org sources to lldb for iOS soon.